# Overflow: visible and XHTML 1.1

Tags: xhtml

I am only using HTML to create forms for our EMR.  When I create a page, and declare it as

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
```

This statement in my CSS stops working

```
.overflow { overflow:visible; }
```

The intended effect is to have a text area that shrinks to fit the text entered when printed.  I have Googled the issue to the best of my abilities and tried every incarnation I could find.

Comment: So it works in normal HTML? That would surprise me.

Comment: Yes.  If I remove the first part, it works.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the "when printed". Hmm, why do you want to use XHTML in the first place? Do you really need it?

Comment: Sorry.  Yes.  Our EMR vendor has us use it to create forms for entering data.  Without it, the calender script they have will not work.